# Отправка AJAX-запроса в Yii-расширение

Tags: ajax, php, yii

Собираю расширение-виджет для загрузки изображений на сервер, частью работы которого явеляется отправка AJAX-запросов на сервер. Исходя из рекомендации с официального сайта, что расширения должны быть самодостаточными, пытаюсь заставить его отправлять AJAX-запросы в обработчик, который находится в папке самого расширения, и пока что безуспешно.

Как я представляю себе это на практике:
После выбора изображения в форме скрипт обращается на следующий URL (пример): http://project/ajax/resize, где 'ajax' - это контроллер, а 'resize' - действие, соответсвенно. Данное действие производит необходимые вычисления и возвращает некий результат, который используется в форме.

Есть ли способы заставить эту схему работать? Если есть, то какие? И насколько вообще такое решение правильно? Прошу совета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если это расширение, то его бы модулем сделать, т.к. писать доп контроллер в корень проекта будет не айс.

Модуль - решение.

Попробуй сделать так.

upd

Ну просто обычно виджет-это такая маленькая штука, которая не сильно затрагивает действия с контроллерами.

Просто вывести что-нибудь, а когда дело про создание контроллера - то тут модуль

+ есть еще  [такое](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/146/how-to-use-a-widget-as-an-action-provider)

Comment: >>>писать доп контроллер в корень проекта будет не айс
Согласен, этого я и хочу избежать. Но меня сильно смущает писать для виджета целый модуль. Хотя может быть я не прав

Comment: Решил проблему схоже с описанием в руководстве по ссылке, котору Вы дали. Спасибо